# Locating a Persistent Object in a DXGrid with Server-Mode Enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm using a `DXGrid` bound to a datasource of `XPServerCollectionSource`, and the `XPServerCollectionSource` is connected to a MSSQL database with 100,000+ records.

The point is that when I add a new record to my datasource , I want to locate it in my `DXGrid` by selecting it, but I don't know how. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6559 which show the "basic" way of doing such a thing...

Comment: unfortunately this is not my answer. In the link you provided there is a sample that the DataSource is not in Server-Mode and I'm sure it dose not contains 100K+ data records. because if you implement the sample for 100k+ records and try to iterate all data it will take about 40 min to complete. and that is not acceptable.